# Would it be possible to call this generic method?

Tags: java, generics

Given the following method of a class which doesn't have type T defined:

`public <T> T get(java.lang.String name) { /* compiled code */ }`

Would it be possible to invoke this, and how?

Comment: A method of what class? The context of your question is much too vague, please elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just call it with an explicit type argument:

```
 foo.<Integer>get("something")
```

I'm not terribly fond of how type arguments are expressed in Java, but they're perfectly doable. See the [Java Generics Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) for another example.

Comment: I don't think the type witness is even always necessary; `Collections.empty*()`, for example, infers from assignment or parameter types.

Comment: @chrylis I think they've improved this in Java 8. You rarely need to supply the type now.